# How to get role id of our own bot in a server

Tags: discord.js

I want to compare positions of 2 roles and I know how to do that I just don't know how to get roleID of our own bot I know we have to use
`<Guild>.me.roles` but I'm still not able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const roles = guild.me.roles.cache;
let roleId;
for (const role of roles) {
  if (role.managed && role.members.has(guild.me)) {
    roleId = role.id;
  }
}
console.log("Own role id is:", roleId);
```

maybe work